# z-index not working with material ui reactjs | how can I show an element top?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modern-ui

I want to show another `Box` component above `Modal` component. Both are material ui component.

There is `Parent Box component` and there is another `Box component` inside `Parent Box component`.

Thing I want to do is show the `second/child Box component` on the top.

Right now it seems like the `second/child Box component` is under the image.

You can click a `open modal` button and inspect modal.
You will see there will be `<img />`, `<div></div>` and `<svg />`

`<div></div>` should be `Box component` but I can't see it over the top.

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box  // parent Box component
          sx={{
            ...style,
            width: width,
            height: height
          }}
          className={classes.imageExpand}
        >
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/06/13/15/36/grain-7260250__340.jpg"
            alt="sample"
            className={classes.imageExpand}
          />
          <Box className={classes.conainer} />  // child Box component
          <CloseIcon className={classes.closeIcon} />
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
```

#### Attempts

1, set `z-index:1000` and `position:'relative'`

2, set lower `z-index` to the parent component

3, `z-index:'1000 !important'`

4, set `transform` and `opacity`

None of them worked. Is there any other way to show `<Box />` top?

I even tried to switch `Box component` to regular `div tag` and this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several MUI components utilize `z-index`, employing a default z-index scale in MUI that has been designed to properly layer drawers, modals, snackbars, tooltips, and more.
The z-index values start at an arbitrary number, high and specific enough to ideally avoid conflicts:

```
mobile stepper: 1000
fab: 1050
speed dial: 1050
app bar: 1100
drawer: 1200
modal: 1300
snackbar: 1400
tooltip: 1500
```

so you should use a z-index greater than 1300.

you can get more info at https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/z-index/